# PDPTE Invalid Bits

Tags: assembly

I’m trying to debug a copy of Apple’s XNU kernel. I am running it in VirtualBox, but whenever the boot loader transfers control of the processor to XNU, the VM monitor aborts execution due to a fatal hardware exception. Investigation reveals that XNU has not set the reserved bits in the PAE PDPTE to zero. Can someone tell me what those reserved bits are (preferably in relation to the rest of the PAE PDPTE)? Assembler is not my forte, and I am at my wits’ end trying to debug the issue.

In case you’re wondering, I have the following C code that defines the data that is being used as the PDPTE:

```
#define PML4_PROT (INTEL_PTE_VALID | INTEL_PTE_WRITE)
pml4_entry_t BootPML4[PTE_PER_PAGE] __attribute__((section("__HIB, __bootPT"))) = {
    [0]                 = ((uint64_t)(PAGE_SIZE) | PML4_PROT),
    [KERNEL_PML4_INDEX] = ((uint64_t)(PAGE_SIZE) | PML4_PROT),
};
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the PDPTE entry? looks like the top level PML4

Answer (score 0):

I've talked to a then-Sun engineer at LinuxTag Berlin once, because MirBSD was getting a SIGILL in GCC-compiled x86 code (BSD gzip, no inline asm or something) in VirtualBox. Turns out that they *know* their emulation is incomplete and buggy (and only slightly better if you enable hardware acceleration, but then you cannot debug as easily), that they know about it and cannot fix it (because that would cost money, and Windows® and Linux® run in it even without the fix).

I'm using qemu for debugging myself, with [this ~/.gdbinit](https://www.mirbsd.org/cvs.cgi/contrib/hosted/tg/.gdbinit?rev=HEAD) (for a 16-bit or 32-bit guest; if your OS runs in 64 bit do be aware that [gcc can crash when switching between 32-bit and 64-bit modes on the fly](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2010-02/msg00053.html) – the thread linked not the exact link I was remembering, but explaining the problem too), GNU screen, and the invocations:

```
 # screen tab 1
$ qemu -S -gdb tcp:127.0.0.1:1234 -m 64 -icount auto -hda foo.img
 # screen tab 2
$ gdb
(gdb) qemu
(gdb) c16           # to switch display to 16-bit mode
(gdb) b *0x07C00    # to set a breakpoint on where the MBR will be loaded at
(gdb) c             # to start the emulation
```

With my .gdbinit you have the command `u` and `uu 10` to disassemble the next (next 10) command(s), `t` to “trace” DEBUG.COM-like (disassemble the next command, step into it, dump the registers and the next 3 commands), `c16` and `c32` to switch modes, and `d 0x1234 0x5678 16b` (e.g.) to display 16 bytes at real-mode address 1234:5678h (just use gdb's `x` command directly in 32-bit mode).

Comment: I’ve tried that; it doesn’t help. I still think XNU is at fault here.

Comment: I compiled my XNU myself. The sources are available at https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel . In addition, no SSE extensions are being used where I believe the crash is coming from. I think it has something to do with rebasing the kernel page tables into higher memory, then loading them into `%cr3`.

Comment: The code file in question is viewable at: https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/start.s

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44828/discussion-between-wjk-and-mirabilos)